# Should KDB views contain side effects or not?

Tags: kdb

In this article on views (https://code.kx.com/q/learn/views/) it is explicitly stated that views should not contain side effects.

However, in this article (https://code.kx.com/q/style/sam/) it is stated "SAM is an abstract model of q applications. Think of SAM as having an inner core and an outer layer. The inner core of SAM consists of variables and constants interconnected by views. All functions, and all views expressed in terms of them are completely free of side effects. **All side effects in the core are explicitly located in views**."

These 2 statements seem to conflict. Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trust the article on **views**.

Apologies for the confusion. The SAM article was adapted from a 1995 paper “Remarks on Style” written by Stevan Apter, and should probably have been omitted, as were sections on windowing. The style ‘remarks’ would be better hosted at [GitHub.com/qbists](https://github.com/qbists) and maintained by the community; I’ll see about moving them there.

**Update 2023.02.10** *Remarks on Style* now moved to GitHub [qbists/style](https://github.com/qbists/style), with a new section on trailing semicolons.

While the source for this material has long been on GitHub and open for contribution, I’m hoping hosting it in Qbists will attract more content. For example, what is good style with tables? With IPC?

Comments to librarian@code.kx.com; PRs to